# Wormtongue's reward

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Is it ever specifically stated that Wormtongue's reward for working for Saruman would be Éowyn or is it just implied? As for other rewards, if Wormtongue were to get Éowyn would that have been the only thing he received or would he have been made something like "The Lesser Lord of Isengard " (or something similar)?

Comment: I read that was Worm *tail*, and was thinking "what are you talking about, he got a silver hand".

Comment: Even if it wasn't explicitly stated, **culturally** it was 100% implied that he would get her if he wanted her. That's the way things USUALLY worked out in cultures of the kind Tolkien described, thoughout human history.

Comment: Well Eomer thought that what Wormtongue wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is never stated. The discussion of reward, assuming there was a discussion, must obviously have been strictly between Saruman and Gríma, and we're never shown that. All that is stated is what Gandalf accused Gríma of:

> 'What was the promised price? When all the men were dead, you were to pick your share of the treasure, and take the woman you desire? Too long have you watched her under your eyelids and haunted her steps.'

(Book III, Chapter 6, "The King of the Golden Hall")

Here, even Gandalf seems to admit that he does not know for certain what the agreement was. He does, however, have an ability to read people, as evidenced by his remark when Frodo was recovering in Rivendell:

> 'You have talked long in your sleep, Frodo,' said Gandalf gently, 'and it has not been hard for me to read your mind and memory.

(Book II, Chapter 1, "Many Meetings")

It is not unreasonable to infer, then, that Gandalf in this instance has quite a good idea of what he's talking about, and that Gríma was indeed promised Éowyn, and some share of treasure. No share in the lordship of Isengard seems to have been implied in any case.

I can find no other reference to any "reward" requested or offered between Gríma and Saruman.

Comment: In regards to land, any do any sources state that Wormtongue would rule over what was left of Rohan?

Comment: No. There's no indication anywhere in the books of any other kind of "reward" for him.

Comment: But I don't recall what there might be in the movies. I haven't seen them since they came out in theaters.

Comment: Wormtongue didn't really have the force of personality to command Saruman's other followers -- either the men of Dunland or the Uruk-hai, both of whom had their own chieftains. So it's doubtful there would be anyone for him to rule if the people of Rohan were killed or driven off.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with Matt Gutting's answer, because Eomer also agreed that was part of the price. Expanded quote:

> How long is it since Saruman bought you? What was the promised price? When all the men were dead, you were to pick your share of the treasure, and take the woman you desire? Too long have you watched her under your eyelids and haunted her steps.'
>
> **Eomer grasped his sword. 'That I knew already,' he muttered.** 'For that reason I would have slain him before, forgetting the law of the hall. But there are other reasons.' He stepped forward, but Gandalf stayed him with his hand.
>
> **'Eowyn is safe now,' he said.**

(emphasis mine)

So Eomer agrees Gandalf guessed correctly the reward, and Wormtongue made no answer to gainsay it. Though what he might have done with a shield-maiden as Eowyn makes me think it would have been no reward at all.

Comment: If Saruman were to install Grima as a puppet King of Rohan, then a marriage with Eowyn would have made perfect sense to legitimize his rule. There's no shortage of forced marriages in the books: Eöl and Aredhel is one example.

Comment: "It is not said that Aredhel was wholly unwilling". If she were, I bet Eöl couldn't have done anything. If Grima tried to marry Eowyn, I bet he would come down with a case of dagger-in-bowels.

Comment: I read that as Eomer simply saying he was aware of Wormtongue's behaviour (the watching and the haunting), not that he knew what the agreed reward was.